# SEO impact of using a Android app download splash page before the home page

Tags: seo, google-search

I have a splash page that user can decide to enter the website or download the android .apk file. I wonder that using the splash page have a bad SEO impact since its a static page with little keywords and related rich contents?

Does Google prefer to see updated content in the first page every time it crawls my website?

Comment: How is the splash page implemented?   Is it only at the root URL?  If a visitor follows a deep link into your site, do the see the splash page?   How about a use from Google search?   Can you get to your home page without seeing the splash page by visiting the home page URL directly?

Comment: Why do you want people to use an Android app anyway?   Does the app require special hardware access that you can't do through a web app?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If a visitor follows a deep link, the content of that link would be served and the splash page does not appear. the splash page only appears when the domain.com is requested by the user and the website home page is available on the link: domain.com/?browse=true. And yes It is a android App store which needs application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google determines how a visitor would view your page that comes from its search engine. If your homepage has an amazing article about "cupcakes" and a user searches Google for "cupcakes", Google will want to send them to your page that has an amazing article about "cupcakes". It will not want to send them to a page that requests for them to download your app.

In other words, if you're trying to rank your site for certain keywords, it's not going to work very well if you offer a splash download page. Google wants to send users to content rich pages.

Googlebot and organic search traffic visitors visit your page very similarly to how someone would visit your page if they typed your domain into their browser. Googlebot, organic traffic, and direct traffic are all coming from a non-http_referrer. In other words, Googlebot and the traffic coming from Google will likely see your splash page.

If you want to fix this issue, you need to identity what traffic is not coming from Google. One way to do this would be through logging a cookie, or logging the user's IP address. When a user comes to your site, and has already been there, then it is ok to show the splash page. But in terms of showing a splash page directly to organic traffic first time visitors, I don't think Google is going to like that page very much.